# Zend framework: Redirect to url with parameters donsen't work

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect

I want to send parameters with url , I try these both ways

**First way**

```
return $this->_helper->redirector->gotoSimple('index','visit','visits',$params);
```

and this way

```
$urlOptions = array('module' => 'visits', 'controller' => 'visit'
            , 'action' => 'index', 'page' => 'add');

 $this->_helper->redirector->gotoRoute($urlOptions);
```

and the url becomes like this

```
 http://localhost/zendApps/InspectionSys/public/visits/visit/index/page/add
```

but the redirection goes to the default page not to add page!

Comment: is `page` a variable or is `page` a different web page you are trying to navigate to? If `page` is a variable you are passing put it in an array and call it a day. If `page` is a web page you are trying to navigate to you are completely incorrect. Either call the `page` as an action in a controller or call `page` as a url using `$this->_redirector('url/to/page');`

Comment: @RockyFord: It is recommended to add a `return` to the line.  I've had problems in the past where the redirection wasn't working correctly because of that.  The line would be: `return $this->getHelper('redirector')->gotoUrl('/url/to/page');`

Comment: `_redirector` and `getHelper('Redirector')` are different methods. As for the `return` thing, who recommends this? In what context? and where can I see to documentation. I really want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->_helper->redirector('index', 'visit', 'visits', array('page' => 'add'));
```

You need to pass the params into an array. That way, you can pass as many as you like.

Comment: are you sure? are you using only "redirector"? remove the "gotoSimple"! here works ;~~

Comment: yes I try it but it dosn't work, I wonder if there are any configurations I should add to application.ini for routing ?

Comment: of course you need the default routing. messing there is not recommended.

Comment: Can you show me what should I add to application.ini and it's good to know that I have 3 modules in the system!

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear what the "add" page is. If it's `addAction()` within the `VisitController`, then you need:

```
$this->_helper->redirector('add', 'visit', 'visits');
```

If the "add" page is a variant within `indexAction()` of `VisitController`, then you need to read the `page` parameter and do something different within the action.

Comment: Add page is the page that adds the visit information, I want to return a result that shows the success or failure of the addition process to the Add page, I try also the redirecotr method but also it doesn't work, I doubt that it's a configuration problem !

Comment: If the is really ` /zendApps/InspectionSys/public/visits/visit/index/page/add`, the the redirection has worked correctly and it should display the output of indexAction() within VisitController.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I guess this post is old but thought I'd answer anyway.  I was having the same issue, and I realized that my problem was how I was setting my form action.  At first I had something like this:

```
<form action="user/add" method="post">
```

Then I changed it to this and the problem was solved:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'user', 'action'=>'add')) ?>" method="post">
```